# Unable to run unix commands on remote server from a file during ssh

Tags: python

I want to run some unix commands on a remote server using a file which stores all the command.

when i type this on local host:-

```
ssh user@server  bash < /some/path/ssh_file.sh
```

this runs the command stored in the file with a warning `Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor)`

but when i try to do this in a python script i'm unable to get anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
command ="#!/bin/bash\n"
command += "df -k /app\n"
command += "ls\n"
f = file("/some/path/ssh_file.sh",'w')
f.write(command)
 ps = subprocess.Popen("ssh user@server bash < /some/path/ssh_file.sh",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
out,err = ps.communicate()
print out,err
```

output:-

```
 None
```

can anybody point out the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the file handler, and `command` is not saved. Call `f.close()` before `Popen`.

Answer (score 2):

While what the others say is absolutely correct, I think your way of doing it is more complicated than needed.

you can reduce it to

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
command = "" # "#!/bin/bash\n" # not needed if we pipe it
command += "df -k /app\n"
command += "ls\n"
ps = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "user@server", "bash"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = ps.communicate(command)
print out, err
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the cmd file after writing to it.

Add the following line after `f.write(command)`

`f.close()`

It will work.

Edited to add:

Another option is that you can using the `with` keyword to automatically close the file, as follows:

```
with open("/some/path/ssh_file.sh",'w') as f:
    f.write(command)
```

The above will close the file after the nested block execution is over.